# PHP Assigning Primary Key and Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I'm trying to assign a Product to a Category and the only solution that I thought of is assigning the Primary Key (Category Id in class Category) with the Foreign Key (Category Id in class Product).

Do i have to do something with the SQL code or change the code in the index.php?

The codes are to show readers what I have done!

Class

```
public class Category {
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    }
public class Product{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int CategoryId{get;set;}
    public String Brand {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price{get;set;
}
```

mydatabase sql

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`brand` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`barcode` INT NOT NULL,
`price` DECIMAL NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `category_id`, `brand`, `name`,`barcode`,`price`) VALUES
(1,1,'Coca Cola','Coke',123456789,0.99)

CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`category_name` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `category_name`) VALUES
(1,'Drinks')
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>CategoryId</th>
                          <th>Brand</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Barcode</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include_once 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['category_id'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['brand'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['barcode'] . '</td>';
                  echo '<td>'. $row['price'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }

                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>

              <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
              <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <p>
              <a href="createCategory.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
              </p>
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>CategoryId</th>
                <th>Category Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            include_once 'database.php';
            <?php
            $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row) {
                 echo '<tr>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td width=250>';
                 echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                 echo '&nbsp;';
                 echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                 echo '</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';

             }
             Database::disconnect();
            ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
      <!--              <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                    </p>
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>CategoryId</th>
                      <th>Catengory Name</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id DESC';
                  foreach ($pdo->query($sql2) as $row) {
                       echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                       echo '<td>'. $row['category_name'] . '</td>';

                       echo '<td width=250>';
                       echo '<a class="btn" href="readCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                       echo '&nbsp;';
                       echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="updateCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                       echo '&nbsp;';
                       echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteCategory.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                       echo '</td>';
                       echo '</tr>';
                     </div>
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table> -->
```

Comment: If you’re just getting started with PHP development and want to make applications, pick a
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your style and needs. These come with many examples that illustrate how to do exactly what you’re asking for here. This code you've presented mixes model, view and controller concerns together into a convoluted stew that's hard to follow and will be very difficult for others to understand. Frameworks espouse conventions that help promote understanding and modularity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think it's too late for me now.

Comment: Maybe for this particular endeavour, but for future ventures you might want to learn one of those so you don't have to re-invent the wheel like you're doing here. Most frameworks have an ORM that handles key assignment and inter-table relationships automatically. It's usually only one or two lines of code to build a one-to-many association. Here you'll need dozens if not more.

Comment: Yeah after your suggestion I just realised how much time I've wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, Primary key and Foreign key are database concepts. You have to make the `category_id` of your *product table* an index and set a foreign key to the `id` of your *category table*.

Comment: Is there SQL coding involve or do I have to do this on phpmyadmin

Comment: Same thing. You can do it as you prefer.